# When downloading windows phone 8 application it show "Attention required, tap here"

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

SA All,

I have a windows phone app which is just updated.
When I try Installing it, it show "Attention required, tap here" and each time I try again it show the same message and nothing happened.

Kindly, advice.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you have other app with the same ID installed on your phone (debug/release version from VS)?

Comment: No, I already remove the debug version then download it from the store.